# @synchronized is taking a lot of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I am using doubango library to make a chat application. It syncs the native contacts from the device but it is taking lot of time if the number of contacts is very high, let's say over 1000 contacts. 
While profiling I figured out that `@synchronized` is taking a lot of time. There is concurrency in Core Data. I have a parent MOC and a child MOC.

I am posting the code, please look at the @synchronized.

```
- (NgnContact *)getNGNGroupContactForConversationId:(NSString*)conversationId managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) moc
{
    NgnContact *contactObj = [[NgnContact alloc]init];

//    NSMutableArray *collectionContactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[CoreDataManager sharedDataManager] getAllContactsAndGroupsFromRCSDBTimeStampSorting : YES managedObjectContext:moc]];

    NSMutableArray *collectionContactList;
   @synchronized([AppDelegate sharedInstance].globalContactListLock)
    {
    collectionContactList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[AppDelegate sharedInstance].globalContactListTimestampSorted];
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"group_id = %@", conversationId];
    NSArray *filteredRCBArry = [collectionContactList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if([filteredRCBArry count] > 0)
    {
        contactObj = [filteredRCBArry objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return contactObj;
}
```

Can you suggest me any ways to optimize the code?  I have tried atomic, lock and unlock but that didn’t solved my concurrency issues.

Comment: How long does it take if you only have one thread and remove the synchronization?

Comment: I would try running `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` inside of the synchronized block, directly on the global contact list instead of having to create a copy. If that shows a significant improvement, copying the array is your actual bottleneck.

Comment: The "collection contact list" is  here is like the contact list of the user in app like what's app. User can do CRUD operations on it. In a multi-threading app it has to be synchronized. Is there any efficient way. Please find the attachments I have linked my coredata manager and app delegate of the app in  the google drive.

Comment: Please put relevant code -- and _only_ the relevant code -- into the question _here_, not behind a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder what makes you think that @synchronized is the problem. In my experience, @synchronized takes dozens of nanoseconds, that's all. Within the @synchronized statement you call globalContactListTimestampSorted - how long does that method take? And you make a copy of that array; that will take time.

And then you use a rather inefficent method to find an object with the right group_id. If you do that a lot then you should really have a dictionary with group_id as key. Possible have a relation group_id -> database record in your database.

Even this should be a lot faster:

```
@synchronized([AppDelegate sharedInstance].globalContactListLock)
{
    for (NgnContact* contact in [AppDelegates sharedInstance].globalContactListTimestampSorted] {
        if ([contact.group_id isEqualToString:conversationId]) {
            contactObj = contact;
            break;
        }
     }
}
```